# Assign values to ViewData from client using MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I inherited an MVC app and am a true novice at it coming from an ASP.NET environment. My problem is I can't manage to move variable data between my partial views and controllers. In ASP.NET this was pretty straight forward, not the case in MVC. So the following code fires when a Tab is selected from the client but I need to capture the selectedTabIndex value from the client and pass it to the controller.

```js
    function onTabSelect(e) {
    var selectedTabIndex = 0;
    selectedTabIndex = $(e.item).index();
    alert(selectedTabIndex);
    }
```

I considered using the ViewData object but there doesn't appear to be a way to make perform this task of assignment from within the function. So the following code would seem to be a ridiculous task and it fails anyway. (Remember, I am an extreme novice at this)

```js
    function onTabSelect(e) {
    var selectedTabIndex = 0;
    <% =ViewData["selectedTabIndex"]%> = selectedTabIndex;      
    }
```

I also considered using cookies but that doesn't seem to be a practical method either. In ASP.NET I could access the client controls using the .find method but this is a steep learning curve for me.

What are my alternatives?

Comment: @Mark: Is the basic functionality goal to generate data/html/json/something *from the server* to be displayed within the tabs when clicked?

Comment: No David, the basic function is to have the partial view to retain the SelectedTabIndex after a Save operation via a submit button has been clicked. The problem is that the SelectedTabIndex value isn't being detected in the controller to persist the value. What I figured would work would be to use the value that has been confirmed to change on every subsequent selection of a different tab, to be captured an assigned within the controller. Does that make sense to you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If different tabs can be selected by the user between Save operations, you might need to consider binding some kind of click function (using jQuery) to set the `selectedTabIndex` javascript variable. Alternatively, you could set a hidden input's value to the selected tab index.

In either case, if you need the value in your controller (to set ViewData, ViewBag, some model data, etc) when a Save operation is submitted, you could submit the data via `$.ajax` and return some JSON from your controller

```
$('#SaveButton').click(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: '/Controller/Save',
    type: 'POST',
    // you might need to serialize additional data you want to save here
    // but you could create any JSON object before calling $.ajax
    data: {"selectedTabIndex": selectedTabIndex}, // data to POST
    dataType: 'json', // this indicates the type of data returned from controller
    success: function(data) {
      // you didn't really describe how to programatically set a tab,
      // so "setToTab" is a guess
      $('#tabID').setToTab(data.selectedTabIndex);
    }
  });
}
```

And your controller might look something like

```
public ActionResult Save(int selectedTabIndex)
{
  // again, you might need different parameters to complete your Save
  return JsonResult(new { selectedTabIndex: selectedTabIndex });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Data is sent to a controller via a `HTTP POST`. Create a hidden input `<input type="hidden" name="selectedTabIndex"/>` and set the value with javascript prior to `POST`. The controller can extract this value from the Form parameters, or it can be autopopulated in the Action method if the method contains a parameter matching the input name.

This is a non-ajax alternative to the [answer provided by David](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6111232/can-you-assign-values-to-viewdata-from-the-client-using-mvc/6112210#6112210).